# How can we capture the REQUEST_URI into an Apache variable and after third party SSO authentication?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, http-headers

How can we capture the `REQUEST_URI` into an Apache variable and after third party SSO authentication?

We have a third party SSO authentication in place, which is working fine. After successful authentication, the third-party tool redirects to our main application (`mainApp`) along with a few HTTP header variables. The successful URL mapped in SSO redirect is `https://example.com/mainApp/*`.

For Example:
User requests URL: `https://example.com/mainApp/page=123` => Goes to SSO Authentication => Redirects to our application URL with http header variable => `https://example.com/mainApp/page=123`.

High level Architecture is
Apache => SSO Auth => Tomcat Application

But we have a new sub-application after our main app. For example `https://example.com/mainApp/appA/page=123`, since the third-party SSO always redirects to the main application which is `mainApp`, how can we capture the user request URL and redirect to the original request?

The current setting is done in the vhosts file with `<Location /mainApp>`.

Is it possible to capture the `REQUEST_URI` into an Apache variable before hitting the SSO auth and after successful auth; Substitute into main app URL,
And redirect to user request URL which is our sub-application? Basically, we want to substitute the sub application after SSO Auth.

I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: "capture the REQUEST_URI into an Apache variable" - It's a bit confusing referring to REQUEST_URI throughout your post, since this is already an "Apache variable"? "before hitting the SSO auth and after successful auth" - before _and_ after? Isn't the URL that you need to redirect to already sent back in an "http header" from the SSO process? How does this interact/conflict with the "sub-application"?

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry, I typed in hurry. You are right it’s an already Apache Variable.
We have a successful URL hardcoded in SSO configuration; which is our main app like this: https://example.com/mainApp/page=123 (1*). After successful authentication, it is redirecting to the main app (1*) We have a sub-app (/appA) under the main app, example https://example.com/mainApp/appA/page=123 (2*) 
When the user hits the sub-app URL (2*); after successful authentication, the SSO is redirecting to the main application URL (1*) instead of sub-application (2*). How to redirect to sub app.